# C# - Docker, handling system files dependency of .dll files

Tags: c#, docker, dll, flir

I'm building a docker image for C# project using .NET framework. I have the relevant .dll files in the docker, in this case FLIR SDK dll's. However, when I run the docker, it throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException as follows.

```
Unhandled Exception: Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalException: Cannot create internal object. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Flir.FormatPlugin.IRSDK.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at Flir.Atlas.Image.IrsdkWrapper..ctor()
   at Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalImage.Initialize()
   at Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalImageFile.Initialize()
   at Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalImageFile..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalImageFile..ctor()
   at Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalImageFile..ctor(Stream path, FileMetaData metaData)
```

**OS:Windows11, VS:2022, .NET Framework:4.8**

I'm using this image in my Dockerfile
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8`

I tried the dependency walker to trace the dependencies. I have all the FLIR `.dll`'s listed in the dependency walker included in the docker. However, the walker shows system32 files as below [image: dependency walker trace]

I replicated the above error locally by renaming the dependent `.dll` file in the bin/Debug folder and got the same error trace as above.

If these system level files are not part of base image how to handle these system files dependency or is the error due to any other issue? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency issue related to FLIR systems was resolved by installing VCredist